# Как разархивировать .jar архив с помощью c++

Tags: c++, zip, поиск-библиотек

Я создаю программу на c++ в VS2019. Мне потребовалось разархивировать jar архив в определённую папку программой. Уже пробовал zlib, не помогло. Кто-нибудь знает подходящую библиотеку?